# DataGridView, loop through all rows and multiply if exists

Tags: c#, gridview, datagrid

Hi all I need some help,

I am making a type of "Game of life" game. Anyway I want to check using grid view, if the current cell's neighbor is same value as my current cell. If it is, I want to check for empty space (around the current cell) and add the neighbor's value but with and extra char.

Here is my code:

```
public void check()
{
  Textual txt = new Textual();
  for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; x++)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y < dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells.Count; y++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value == "VS" ||
            dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value == "SL" ||
            dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value == "KG" ||
            dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value == "KN")
        {
          if (y - 1 >= 0 &&
              y + 1 < dataGridView1.ColumnCount &&
              x - 1 >= 0 && x + 1 < dataGridView1.RowCount &&
              y + 1 < dataGridView1.ColumnCount &&
              x + 1 < dataGridView1.RowCount)
          {
            string value = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value.ToString();
            int j;
            int k;
            switch (value)
            {
              case "VS":
              if (dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y + 1].Value == "")
              {
                dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y + 1].Value = "VS++";
                j = x;
                k = y + 1;
                int[,] temp= new int[j, k];
                or.oznaka = "VS";
                popis.TryAdd(temp, or);
                dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y + 1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
              }
              else if (dataGridView1.Rows[x - 1].Cells[y].Value == "")
              {
                dataGridView1.Rows[x - 1].Cells[y].Value = "VS++";
                j = x - 1;
                k = y;
                int[,] temp= new int[j, k];
                or.oznaka = "VS";
                popis.TryAdd(temp, or);
                dataGridView1.Rows[x - 1].Cells[y].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
              }
              else if (dataGridView1.Rows[x + 1].Cells[y].Value == "")
              {
                dataGridView1.Rows[x + 1].Cells[y].Value = "VS++";
                j = x + 1;
                k = y;
                int[,] temp= new int[j, k];
                or.oznaka = "VS";
                popis.TryAdd(temp, or);
                dataGridView1.Rows[x + 1].Cells[y].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold;
              }
              else if (dataGridView1.Rows[x + 1].Cells[y + 1].Value == "")
              {
                dataGridView1.Rows[x + 1].Cells[y + 1].Value = "VS+";
                j = x - 1;
                k = y + 1;
                int[,] temp= new int[j, k];
                or.oznaka = "VS";
                popis.TryAdd(temp, or);
                dataGridView1.Rows[x + 1].Cells[y + 1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
              }
              else if (dataGridView1.Rows[x - 1].Cells[y - 1].Value == "")
              {
                dataGridView1.Rows[x - 1].Cells[y - 1].Value = "VS+";
                j = x - 1;
                k = y - 1;
                int[,] temp= new int[j, k];
                or.oznaka = "VS";
                popis.TryAdd(temp,or);
                dataGridView1.Rows[x - 1].Cells[y - 1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
              }
              else if (dataGridView1.Rows[x - 1].Cells[y + 1].Value == "")
              {
                dataGridView1.Rows[x - 1].Cells[y + 1].Value = "VS+";
                j = x - 1;
                k = y + 1;
                int[,] temp= new int[j, k];
                or.oznaka = "VS";
                popis.TryAdd(temp, or);
                dataGridView1.Rows[x - 1].Cells[y + 1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.HotPink;
              }
              else if (dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y - 1].Value == "")
              {
                dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y - 1].Value = "VS+";
                j = x;
                k = y - 1;
                int[,] temp= new int[j, k];
                or.oznaka = "VS";
                popis.TryAdd(temp, or);
                dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y - 1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lavender;
              }
              else if (dataGridView1.Rows[x + 1].Cells[y - 1].Value == "")
              {
                dataGridView1.Rows[x + 1].Cells[y - 1].Value = "VS+";
                j = x + 1;
                k = y - 1;
                int[,] temp= new int[j, k];
                or.oznaka = "VS";
                popis.TryAdd(temp, or);
                dataGridView1.Rows[x + 1].Cells[y - 1].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
              }
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: So I'll try to be more clear. I have grid. For example object is on (5,5) I need to check all eight directions around him and see if some object has same value as my current object if it has then I need to check around my first object(5,5) if it has empty space and insert some value

Comment: Please update your question instead of clarifying in a comment. When you do that, please also only post relevant bits of code (and indent that code reasonably).

Comment: Please edit your code correctly as I don't enjoy doing it for you...

Comment: Suggestion: Divide your problem into two: First, solve your problem with a simple array (no GUI control involved!). Then solve the problem of updating a `DataGridView` (or some other UI controls) so that it reflects the state of the array. I'm suggesting this because all that `DataGrid`-related code distracts from what's really going on, and updating the GUI is usually trivial if you already have a good backing data source.

Comment: while you are telling me how should I edit my code you could better give me a hand in this problem. Okay I admit I didn't paste it correctly. But I think giving a help and ideas is better than talking about my pasted code...

Comment: yea that's the problem I don't know how to make it that way..trying all day already

Comment: (@denonth, but Killercam is right. Kudos to @Scott M. for having done some hard work. You know, if you want help, it would help if you made this easy for others! Instead you have asked a badly explained question and expect people to read a ton of badly-formatted code. We don't mean to punish you with words; please take this as an advice on how to ask questions here, in a way that ensures you'll quickly receive useful answers.)

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having? Is it not working the way you expect? In what way? Are you getting an error? What is the error? Identifying the problem will help you (and us) solve the problem. No one is likely to solve this entire problem (as is) for you.

Comment: Note: we forget to separate generations, as they are separated in Life game. Easiest way to do it is to add HashSet<DataGridViewCell> and populate it when we make a cell alive. Where we test if cell is not empty we should add a test if HashSet contains this cell and if it does skip further business with this cell. It is just a few lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function you might use to find matching neighbours. It will still be very similar if you opt for two-dimensional array instead of grid, which would be the best solution as controls should be used for interaction with humans and data should be manipulated regardless of presentation.

To find matching value given a cell (mind x and y - you switched usual meaning of them):

```
cell = FindCell(new Point(x, y), dataGridView1.Rows[y].Cells[x]);
```

And to find empty cell:

```
cell = FindCell(new Point(x, y), string.Empty);
```

EDIT: better usage example

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.Value != null && cell.Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
            DataGridViewCell neighbour = FindCell(new Point(cell.ColumnIndex, row.Index), cell.Value.ToString());
            //  Found
            if (neighbour != null)
            {
                DataGridViewCell emptyCell = FindCell(new Point(cell.ColumnIndex, row.Index), string.Empty);
                if (emptyCell != null)
                {
                    emptyCell.Value = "WHATEVERYOUREQUIREITTOBE";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: I assumed from your code your cells will have a non-null value. As it is not so, replace each cell.Value.ToString() with (cell.Value ?? string.Empty).ToString(), as I did in example.

Test for null after to make sure you have found a cell. Here is the function:

```
/// <summary>
/// List of locations around given location. Add to previous value to get next location.
/// </summary>
Point[] neighbours = new Point[]
{
    new Point (-1, -1),
    new Point (1, 0),
    new Point (1, 0),
    new Point (-2, 1),
    new Point (2, 0),
    new Point (-2, 1),
    new Point (1, 0),
    new Point (1, 0),
};

/// <summary>
/// Finds a cell containing given string value.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="location">Point of search</param>
/// <param name="value">Value to find</param>
/// <returns>Cell containing given value</returns>
DataGridViewCell FindCell(Point location, string value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < neighbours.Length; ++i)
    {
        //  Move location to new point
        location.Offset(neighbours[i]);
        //  Check boundaries
        if (location.Y >= 0 && location.Y < dataGridView1.RowCount
            && location.X >= 0 && location.X < dataGridView1.Columns.Count)
        {
            //  Get cell 
            DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.Rows[location.Y].Cells[location.X];
            //  If value matches
            if ((cell.Value ?? string.Empty).ToString() == value)
            {
                return cell;
            }
        }
    }
    //  No match
    return null;
}
```

Comment: this is very good example, what I need is something that will determine same cell around one object. And then find empty space and fill it with some value. Empty space should be around first objects.

Comment: I think I need inside this : `if (cell.Value.ToString() == value)
            {
                return cell;
            }` insert some code that will go around object and insert if there is empty space available.

Comment: This is exactly that. As you move through cells, call this function to find out if it has a neighbour containing the same value; use the same approach to find empty cell. I'll edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: great Nikola one more thing value in method is throwing me null exception

Comment: when I move toString method in your function, sometimes it works but then I get expception when calling `DataGridViewCell neighbour = FindCell(new Point(cell.ColumnIndex, row.Index), cell.Value.ToString())`

Comment: I assumed from your code your cells will have a non-null value. As it is not so, replace each cell.Value.ToString() with (cell.Value ?? string.Empty).ToString(), as I did in example.

Comment: hmm I got all grids populated with your text...something is not working good for me..can you tell me what I need to change in my code so I can make your code work..I just added method and point definition, and ofc this loop for accessing cells.

Comment: okay I got it to work. I see my data inside, but all empty spaces are filled

Comment: Because empty spaces find other empty spaces around. To fix, add a check for empty cells before first call to FindCell.

Comment: before this line : `DataGridViewCell neighbour = FindCell(new Point(cell.ColumnIndex, row.Index), (cell.Value ?? string.Empty).ToString());`

Comment: great great help! Thank you Nikola!

Comment: +1 for the effort here Nikola! Credit to the way stackoverflow works and helps people with issues...